What is the proper use of the tag military-cryptography?
There is no tag summary for military-cryptography. There are only three questions with that tag. Only one of those do I feel has a remotely "military" feel to it. What should this tag be used for or should it even be a tag?

I've removed the tag (and the other random unrelated tags it was decorated with) from this question.

@IlmariKaronen Hi Ilmari, could you please post that as a (separate) answer so this question can be marked answered? Mike, please do accept once that is done, as the tag doesn't exist anymore.

@MaartenBodewes: I added it as an update to my existing answer. Mike, feel free to mark it as answered (or add and accept your own answer if you feel that mine is unacceptable for some reason).

I could see the military-cryptography tag being useful for questions about cryptosystems designed and/or used mostly within the military, as opposed to those designed by the open academic crypto community.
Of course, the big problem with such questions is that the details of such systems tend to be classified, so — aside from historical systems that have been declassified — all we have to go on is rumors, leaks and conjecture.
In any case, none of the current questions using the tag seem like a very good fit for it.  I already removed it from this question, along with a bunch of other random tags that had little if anything to do with the question.  Of the remaining two questions, this one should probably be retagged as standards, plus possibly something more specific (though I'm not sure what).  As for the last one (which I believe introduced the tag), it does kind of make sense there, even if it doesn't quite match how I would personally envision the tag being used.  Anyway, I wouldn't object if someone just removed it from all those questions.

Update: As of 2024, the military-cryptography tag no longer exists on this site.
(According to edit history, I removed the tag from the first two questions linked above shortly after this meta question was asked in 2012. I'm not sure what happened to the third question, because the tag no longer shows up in its edit history at all. But in any case the tag is gone and hasn't existed here for more than a decade now.)
